# AutoScrollPosition alternative in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have an point that I need to pass AutoScrollPosition like this:

```
  pt = new Point(innerPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X, innerPanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

but the problem is DataGridView doesn't have AutoScrollPosition, only AutoScrollOffset. When I tried:

```
  pt = new Point(dataGridView1.AutoScrollOffset.X, dataGridView1.AutoScrollOffset.Y);
```

nothing happens. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what your purpose for this code?

Comment: I need to pass it as a value of one control to a custom control. In my example scrollbar value to custom scrollbar control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AutoScrollOffset Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autoscrolloffset.aspx) :

> A Point specifying the scroll location. The default is the upper-left
>   corner of the control.

So just Do this :

```
Point PT = dataGridView1.AutoScrollOffset;
```

You might also want to try this :

```
Point PT = New Point(dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex,dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex);
```